# Extraction of diff hash from GITHub commit url

Tags: git, github

If you open a GITHub commit, click on the 'changed file' link and click on any one of the changed files, the commit url in the browser will append a diff hash id like this:

'**#diff-3db08c3ce067ae92af324b2d8bd6b5e2**'.

Full URL - https://github.com/google/guava/commit/19c39725be34efafa59edf6238713e97f6565eb1#diff-3db08c3ce067ae92af324b2d8bd6b5e2

Can anybody please explain me what exactly is this diff hash id, is there any git command to generate this id for a changed file?

Comment: This is a SHA-1 hash which uniquely (well, almost uniquely) identifies a given commit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you elaborate on the _"almost uniquely"_ part?

Comment: There is a _very_ unlikely chance that two commits could have the same hash in your repo.  But the Earth's orbit will decay and spiral into the sun before that happens most likely.

Comment: I don't see how that could happen, since git would not allow storing two commits with the same hash

Answer (score 1):

The part after `#diff-` isn't a SHA-1 hash, because it doesn't have 40 characters but rather 32. In fact, if you run this command in your repo:

```
git rev-parse 3db08c3ce067ae92af324b2d8bd6b5e2
```

you'll get this:

> fatal: ambiguous argument '3db08c3ce067ae92af324b2d8bd6b5e2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

So, if I had to guess, I'd say that's a GUID generated by GitHub to keep track of the files included in commit.

Comment: why github didn't use something more obvious such as the hash for the file .. in which you would get with git ls-files??? 


That's really annoying!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it is SHA256 of filename with path.

```
echo -n "path/file" | sha256sum
```

Answer (score 0):

I have by coincidence asked support, and github aswered me that this is non documented.
We should instead use some sort of API to recover the URI.

I don't like the answer but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The 32 characters following "diff-" is an MD5 hash of the path and filename. Here's an example using node.js:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(path+'/'+filename).digest('hex');
```